# Inserting Html, CSS and Javascript into the console to test a new block/feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, console, google-chrome-devtools

I have been tasked with creating a new feature/block of HTML & CSS that contains some light JS for controls (think a carousel). It is working as expected but two of the requirements are that it's one block of code and it can be run in the console and display on the web page(e.g. Chrome)

I have added the CSS and JS into the html file, so one block of code, I hope is solved, I then tried to create a little function using insertAdjacentHTML to run in the console but that doesn't work as it doesn't accept anything other than pure html (no class names or  tags etc)

I do not have access to the source code of the website they want to test it on, so apparently it has to be done in the console.

I also looked at extensions, to see if I can work out how they do it but not having much luck, happy if someone can recommend anyway in which I can display this new feature.

I understand why they want to do it this way as they will want to do quick demos of new features built, but still an unorthodox method imo. Happy to be told wrong.

Any help would be great.

TIA

EDIT: JS file - https://github.com/morphey-slavbard/product_slider/blob/main/main.js
HTML file - https://github.com/morphey-slavbard/product_slider/blob/main/index_2.html

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the requirement, but can't you just paste in the code using your browser's dev tools inspect facility and Edit HTML option (obtained on my browser at least by right clicking on the element you want to change or add stuff to or before or after)?

Comment: I understand you can just edit HTML, but the requirement was the following:
1. Build a new Block or feature e.g. Product carousel
2. Bundle that into one file, e.g. JS, HTML, and CSS
3. Open Dev tools and go to Console and past some form of code in 
4. This will then display the new block inline on the page until there is a refresh.

I completely understand that I can edit the HTML and then just copy it in, but I need some why to inject it for someone that doesn't understand HTML and knowing where it needs to be.

Comment: If you don’t know here it is to go how can you proceed?

Comment: Let me try to be clearer.

This is the HTML file - https://github.com/morphey-slavbard/product_slider/blob/main/index_2.html

If I go to any site e.g https://demo.nopcommerce.com/ and then add the file to the console it obviously won't work, now if I do what you suggested first and edited the HTML (e.g add it after .master-wrapper-content), it can be seen but then the JS does not work for the arrows. What am I missing?